# Lower initial size of an empty dictionary

Tags: python, performance

When I create an empty dictionary in python 3.x and check the size with sys.getsizeof(..) on my machine it returns 240.

Is it possible to lower this?

Comment: Why would you ever need to decrease the size of a dictionary? 240 bytes is minuscule...

Comment: I am trying to implement myself ( without using scipy ) a datastructure for sparse matrices, I would like to get it lower then 200 if possible.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think that kind of optimization is best done as a C/C++ extension, where you will have fuller control over the internals. See https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html for more.

Comment: DOK probably isn't the best representation for storing your matrices in that case, regardless of overhead. It's useful for initially building matrices, but for storing them, consider something like CSR.